# Using a new but potentially dirty olive and barb when shortening hydraulic brake hosing

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake, cleaning

I wish to shorten the hose on a hydraulic brake system (model is TRP hylex)

i have an unused TRP olive and barb, however unfortunately they have been knocking about in a tray with an old chain and general grime

They aren’t visibly dirty but  have been in contact with chain grime and i would like to know if they should be cleaned in a particular way before being installed.

As it happens, without thinking i ran them under tap water so they are now also potentially contaminated with water.

I’ve searched and can’t find any relevant info.

Thanks

Comment: Putting the question in a different perspective you are balancing spending a dollar or two at  you LBS against a concern over brake failure. A useful mantra with brakes (along with nearly everything safety)- 'If in doubt, chuck it out' - *(the PC version just doesn't have the same ring- 'If in doubt, recycle it' )

Comment: I don't really think that mild contamination of these very small components of a brake hose are likely to lead to brake failure - if anything  potentially sub optimal performance? perhaps I am wrong. LBS don't sell TRPs components and online the olive and barbs are only sold as part of a bleed kit (which  I have) or a 10 pack - either would involve generating quite a bit of waste, which is important to me.  I also need to complete this job sooner than any delivery would arrive. I appreciate the sentiment of safety but in this instance I don't think it is unreasonable to clean them myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't 'contaminate' brass with water. Just give them a clean with isopropyl alcohol to get  any dirt or oil off.

Comment: thanks. I guess I was more thinking that there might be water trapped inside the (very narrow) lumen of the olive by capillary action which could contaminate the oil. I'll wash them in IPA

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure whether it's going to be an issue if you leave it, it definitely won't be if you clean it just to be safe. Something like disc brake cleaner will clean off any contamination without leaving a residue behind.